# Evaluate parameter passed to mocked method called from another class

Tags: java, mockito

I am testing a class that use another class I have mocked. One of the outer classes' methods modifies an argument that is passed to the mocked class's method, and I need to check that it was modified correctly.

The code looks something like this:

```java
public class Foo
{
  public boolean performTask(String name, Integer version)
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class Bar
{
  private Foo foo;

  public Bar(Foo foo)
  {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public void doSomething(String name, Integer version)  
  {  
    boolean good = foo.performTask(name, ((version.startsWith("A")) ? null : version));
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to check that if I pass a `name` argument that starts with `A`, then the second argument being passed to `performTask()` is null.

Edit:

As requested, this the start of the unit test:

```
public class BarTest
{
  @Mock
  private Foo mockFoo;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception
  {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception
  {
    Bar bar = new Bar(mockFoo);

    bar.doSomething("ABC", new Integer(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: How does you test look like? I assume that mocking `Foo` and providing the mock to `Bar` would do. Afterwards you can use `Mockito.verify` to ensure that the correct method was invoked.

Comment: All the examples I've seen of using verify involve calling the mock class directly. How do I use it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> All the examples I've seen of using verify involve calling the mock class directly. How do I use it in this case?

Exactly like that. All you need is access to the mock, which you have.

```java
Mockito.verify(mockFoo, Mockito.times(1)).performTask("ABC", null);
```

If its important what the method is supposed to `return` (by default false),
you will need to define the behaviour using:

```java
Mockito.when(mockFoo.performTask("ABC", null)).thenReturn(true);
```

---

Example:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(mockFoo.performTask("ABC", null)).thenReturn(true);

    Bar bar = new Bar(mockFoo);
    bar.doSomething("ABC", new Integer(1));

    Mockito.verify(mockFoo, Mockito.times(1)).performTask("ABC", null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I realize now my mistake was not including the line setting the behavior of the mocked method to return successfully.

Comment: Hey, would this work even if you set the mocked method to return an exception?
i.e. doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockFoo).performTask(anyString(), any());

Comment: Yes, that should be a viable usecase. The exception is thrown after (and because) the mock was invoked so the interaction will be counted.